# Android + Python + webView some problems

Tags: android, python, webview

**Question 1:**

I'm trying to make an android application with python and WebView.

I wonder if I can get a python variable and send it to html and save them in a variable in javascript.

I tried this but does not work:

**script.py**

```
import android
import os, sys


ruta_del_proyecto = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

droid = android.Android()
droid.webViewShow(ruta_del_proyecto + '/ui/prueba.html?ruta_del_proyecto=5')

print ruta_del_proyecto + '/ui/prueba.html?ruta_del_proyecto=5'
```

**prueba.html**

```
<html>
    <!--urta cel: file:///sdcard/sl4a/scripts/test1/ -->
  <head>
    <title>prueba</title>
    <script>
        var droid = new Android(); 

        function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
        }

        var ruta_del_proyecto = getUrlVars()["ruta_del_proyecto"];

        alert (ruta_del_proyecto);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Question 2:**

When I make the script.py in to APK with "The Android Java IDE (AIDE)" , then install and open, WebView don't open

The python code are execute but WebView don't open

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple hack you can do. Webkit WebView has the "load-finished" event that triigers after your page loads and after which you can execute your JavaScript function:

```
def on_load_finished(webview, frame):
    browser.execute_script('your-js-function('+yourVariable+');')

browser = webkit.WebView()
browser.connect("load-finished", on_load_finished)
```

Remember, you can pass dictionaries as an argument by serializing them with json module and deserializing them in JS!